# extract visible text from all elements in Chrome browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, innertext

I am writing javascript that collects all visible text and put them in a table one by one in rows. This script willl only run in chrome so there is no need to worry about compatibility. I've tried innerText and textContents but they both appear to return data from HTML, SCRIPTS and other tags.
They also gets text from child, so putting one in each row doesn't work.
It would be just great if innerText can return me the unstyled text (as if you copied-pasted into notepad) of what is displayed on the browser.

Comment: `document.body.textContent`

Comment: still returns whole lot of scripts. also it is returned as single string and not an array. try amazon.com

Comment: Then you'll have to write something that exclude script tags etc.

Comment: i can do that. but that isn't the only issue. as i stated, it is getting data from child as well. so for example if you have <DIV><Span>gift card</span><span>go to home</span></div> they would show up as one string when i do innerText on DIV. I am basically calling getElementByTagName(*) and calling innerText on all of them, excluding SCRIPT and NOSCRIPT